# Update on Ubuntu - coloured lines around everything

Tags: nvidia, upgrade, kernel, graphics

Everyday I check for updates on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I updated to 4.4.0-65-generic today and now on everything I'm getting thick rainbow coloured lines around every dialog box in every program. My setup is pretty standard. Skylake i5-6500, Nvidia 950gtx. Does anyone know how to fix it?

[image: Look at the dialog box]

Comment: This is a known bug. Remove drivers from the PPA and install the default `nvidia-367`. The latest drivers are not always the best.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a guide on how to do this?

Comment: OK. I will write an answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug with unofficial Nvidia drivers that you installed from a PPA.

The 375-378 drivers my be recommended by Nvidia at their site, but they are not tested for Ubuntu and not recommended by Canonical.

Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-367
```

and reboot.

Comment: Will this cause a problem with CUDA and tensorflow? I'm having the same problem but I rather see this than not have tensorflow working!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I have Nvidia Quadro 600. It was using Proprietary  driver version 375.39. Then I reversed back to an older version 304.135. and the issue was solved.